# Oracle - junction tables and connect to prior

Tags: oracle, hierarchical-data, connect-by

I have problem that I think is only solvable with a Connect-to-prior statement.

My data model is, simplified, as follows:

```
create table TASK
 ( TASK_ID number
);
create table ITEM
 ( TASK_ID number,
   NEXT_TASK_ID number
);    
create table TASK_ITEM
 ( TASK_ID number,
   ITEM_ID number
);
```

a set of items are combined into a task. A set for tasks are combined into one or more items (this is where the TASK_ITEM junction-table comes in). The process starts with a set of items, and ends with a single item (ITEM.NEXT_TASK_ID is null for the last item, and no task_item's exist for the first items).

**My problem:**

**Given one task_id *I want to extract all preceding tasks*.**

This is a problem bordering on those described in [Philip Greenspun's excellent introduction to trees in Oracle](http://philip.greenspun.com/sql/trees.html), or in [Wikibook's description of Hierarchical Queries](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_Dialects_Reference/Select_queries/Hierarchical_Queries), but can't seem to find any good solutions tackling these problems when they include more ID's and a Junction table.

My own SQL-foo falls sadly short, and I've googled my heart out without finding a solution to my particular problem.

In the voice of Carrie Fisher: *Help me Stack Overflow, you're my only hope.*

Comment: Could you include a few rows of data? [it looks like some information might be redundant in your model]

Comment: Shouldn't "a set of items are combined into a task" rather read "a set of task items are combined into a task" ?

Comment: @phareim: Your problem is `"Given one task_id I want to extract all preceding tasks."` ,then why we need table `TASK_ITEM AND TASK ` It can be easily found by Only one table ITEM ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Seek and you shall find.*

With the help of a colleague we sorted this out.

The trick I hadn't managed to see for my self is to first join the required information together, *then* do the *connect to*-statement.

I think the code below solves the problem as it's described.

```
select parent_task.* 
    from (
    select  parent_task_id, item_id, task_id, level
        from (
            select 
                task.task_id parent_task_id, 
                task_item.item_id, 
                item.task_id task_id
            from 
                task, task_item, item
            where 
                task_item.task_id = task.task_id
            and 
                item.item_id = task_item.item_id) properly_structured_parent_table    
        start with task_id = :TASK_ID
        connect by prior parent_task_id = task_id 
    ) task_hierarchy, task parent_task
where parent_task.task_id = task_hierarchy.task_id;
```

The inner mot SQL builds a proper parent_table. The next build a hierarchy using *connect by prior*. The outermost SQL joins in the rest of the data as required in the application.

Thank you for your time and feedback folks.